# How to create a new data in Laravel Livewire without refresh the page

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires

I have a problem with the Laravel Livewire CRUD application. when I create data after inserting successfully and resetting the form I can't create new data. I should just refresh the page and then create new data. without refreshing the page it doesn't allow me to create data.

Store function is:

```
public function store()
{
     $this->validate();
      auth()->user()->reminders()->create([
          'body' => $this->body,
          'frontend' => $this->frontend,
          'date' => $this->date,
          'time' => $this->time,
      ]);
      $this->resetInputs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
use submit.prevent
<form wire:submit.prevent="store">
do not use button click
 <button wire:click="store">Craate</button>
</form>
```